# Объект в массив байт

Tags: serialize, java, tcp

Сервер принимает массив байт, который в свою очередь представляет из себя объект с примитивными типами в качестве полей! Нужно сериализовать объект и отправить массив байт. Загвоздка в том, что [serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) не помогает и сервер ругается, насколько я понял, потому что добавляется куча вспомогательной инфы! На C# это реализовано через Marshal и работает! Как это реализовать на java?

Comment: то есть, Вам нужно научиться на java сериализировать в формат, который совместимый с C#?

Comment: @KoVadim, формат, такой же, какой сериализует C#

Comment: Лучше берите независимый формат - json, xml, bson. А внутренние проприетарные протоколы - это всегда боль.